# How to abstract a base class with a specified method?

Tags: python

Say all subclass can get its own choice like `class.choice()`

```
from enum import IntEnum

class CompanyType(IntEnum):
    BySelf = 1
    Agency = 2

    @staticmethod
    def choice():
        return  [
        (i.value, i.name) for i in CompanyType
    ]


class CompanyStatus(IntEnum):
    StartUp = 1
    LargeCompany = 2

    @staticmethod
    def choice():
        return [
            (i.value, i.name) for i in CompanyStatus
        ]
...
```

How can I abstract a base class that can be inherited with method `choice`

Expected as:

```
from enum import IntEnum

class ChoiceBase_():

    @staticmethod
    def choice():
        return [
            (i.value, i.name) for i in specified_subclass
        ]


class CompanyType(ChoiceBase_, IntEnum):
    BySelf = 1
    Agency = 2


class CompanyStatus(ChoiceBase_, IntEnum):
    StartUp = 1
    LargeCompany = 2


print(CompanyType.choice())
print(CompanyStatus.choice())
```

Comment: This looks like what `@classmethod` is for.

Comment: Can't you just raise an exception in `ChoiceBase.__init__` if `type(self)` is `ChoiceBase`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `classmethod` decorator in order to get the classes constants:

```
class ChoiceBase_():
    @classmethod
    def choice(cls):
        return [(i.value, i.name) for i in cls]


class CompanyType(ChoiceBase_, IntEnum):
    BySelf = 1
    Agency = 2


class CompanyStatus(ChoiceBase_, IntEnum):
    StartUp = 1
    LargeCompany = 2


print(CompanyType.choice())
print(CompanyStatus.choice())
```

Out:

```
[(1, 'BySelf'), (2, 'Agency')]
[(1, 'StartUp'), (2, 'LargeCompany')]
```

**Edit:**

In Python36, inheriting from `int` makes sure to use `use int.__new__()` as stated in the error message:

```
from enum import Enum
class CompanyStatus(int, ChoiceBase_, Enum):
    StartUp = 1
    LargeCompany = 2
```

Comment: works on `3.7+` but failed with `3.6.6` as `TypeError: object.__new__(CompanyType) is not safe, use int.__new__()` How to avoid this error ?